# How to use StructOpt to parse an argument into a Vec without it being treated as multiple arguments?

Tags: rust, structopt

I have this code:

```
#[derive(StructOpt)]
pub struct Opt {
    /// Data stream to send to the device
    #[structopt(help = "Data to send", parse(try_from_str = "parse_hex"))]
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

fn parse_hex(s: &str) -> Result<u8, ParseIntError> {
    u8::from_str_radix(s, 16)
}
```

This works for `myexe AA BB`, but I need to take `myexe AABB` as input.

Is there a way to pass a custom parser to `structopt` to parse `AABB` into a `Vec<u8>`? I need to parse only the second form (no space).

I know I can do it in 2 steps (storing into a `String` in the struct then parse it, but I like the idea that my `Opt` has the final type for everything.

I tried a parser like this:

```
fn parse_hex_string(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<u8>, ParseIntError>
```

The `StructOpt` macro panics about type mismatches because it seems to produce a `Vec<Vec<u8>>`.

Comment: As I said, the custom parser I'm using right now works for `myexe AA BB` (note the space between the params) but I need to take `myexe AABB` with no space. I tried a parser like this`fn parse_hex_string(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<u8>, ParseIntError>` but the structopt macro panics about type mismatching because it seems to produce a `Vec<Vec<u8>>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

StructOpt makes the distinction that a `Vec<T>` will always map to multiple arguments:

> `Vec<T: FromStr>`
>
> list of options or the other positional arguments
>
> `.takes_value(true).multiple(true)`

That means you need a single type to represent your data. Replace your `Vec<u8>` with a newtype:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct HexData(Vec<u8>);

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
pub struct Opt {
    /// Data stream to send to the device
    #[structopt(help = "Data to send")]
    data: HexData,
}
```

This leads to the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `HexData: std::str::FromStr` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
16 | #[derive(StructOpt)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::str::FromStr` is not implemented for `HexData`
   |
   = note: required by `std::str::FromStr::from_str`
```

Let's implement `FromStr`:

```
impl FromStr for HexData {
    type Err = hex::FromHexError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        hex::decode(s).map(HexData)
    }
}
```

And it works:

```
$ cargo run -- DEADBEEF
HexData([222, 173, 190, 239])

$ cargo run -- ZZZZ
error: Invalid value for '<data>': Invalid character 'Z' at position 0
```